# Adding input fields in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hi Im currently using this code

```
<div id="inputList">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
      var input = document.getElementById('inputList').getElementsByClassName("searchTextField")[0];
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          document.getElementById('city1').value = place.name;
          document.getElementById('cityLat1').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
          document.getElementById('cityLng1').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>

  <input class="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />
  <input class="city" id="city1" name="city1" />
  <input class="cityLat" id="cityLat1" name="cityLat" />
  <input class="cityLng" id="cityLng1" name="cityLng" />


 <!--  What to put here?
 <script type="text/javascript">
     ('#addLocation').click(function() {
         ('#inputList').append('??');
     });​
 </script> 
 -->


 <br>
 <input type="button" value="Add New Location" id="addLocation" />
</div>
```

To utilize google autocomplete to populate a field with Lat/Lng of a location. This part works well but I want to be able to add additional, identical input fields after pressing the add location button. Cant figure out how to add them (which parameters to pass to append). Have some basic knowledge but not too familiar with HTML and Javascript, any help is appreciated

Comment: Im trying to work out what you're asking and I don't understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: Are you trying to make browser auto complete fill out multiple inputs?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I have one input text field that utilizes autocomplete and google maps api to fill out a location, then finds the longitude and latitude of that location.  the "city" "citylat" and "citylng" are the values filled in, and will be hidden later.  I have just chosen to show them on page for debugging.  But I am just trying to add multiple identical input fields that use the same autocomplete and google api features when the button is clicked, basically just duplicate the "Enter A Location" field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your inputItems in a div and then duplcate them using jquery `clone()` function.
Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="dataForm">
    <input class="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />
    <div id="listFields1">
        <input class="city" id="city1" name="city1" />
        <input class="cityLat" id="cityLat1" name="cityLat" />
        <input class="cityLng" id="cityLng1" name="cityLng" />
    </div>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Add New Location" id="addLocation" />
```

As you can see, I put all inside a form, then I put your inputs inside a div I called listFields1, that we will be cloning then appending to your form, but before we will change (increment) the cloned list id.

```
$('#addLocation').click(function() {
    // get the last cloned list"
    var list = $('div[id^="listFields"]:last');
    // add 1 to the last number we have on the last listField id
    var num = parseInt( list.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
    // clone the new list to the form
    var newList = list.clone().prop('id', 'listFields'+num ).appendTo( "#dataForm" );;

})
```

You must also change also increment all your ids, as for city, cityLat and cityLng the same as I did for the global list.

Here the working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxfe63o7/4/)

Comment: So the searchTextfield class should also be inside listFields1 as it is in the JSfiddle right? Also, if I want it so that it doesnt duplicate the input i have already it should also have an id that is incremented (after class="searchTextField" declaration)?

Comment: if you check the updated link and the code above, you'll see that the searchTextfield is already out of the listFields1, so it won't be duplicated.

Comment: Hmm Im using your example in my application but the Add Location button does not do anything.  This is what I was looking for though, so the problem probably has to do with the rest of my configuration.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry another quick question, if I am already using a form with other data and input fields, would using your setup(that has another form) work?  Is there a problem with using what I had above with the div id="inputList" then just changing it to .appendTo("#inputList");;

Comment: First, you have to make sure that you are using jquery library, then check and/or change the script with the IDs you are using.
The form I added was just an exemple, so give your form an id that you will update on the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that you aren't using document.getElementById('addLocation'), which (correct me if I'm wrong) is required without some scripts.

The next thing is that you are using JQuery methods here. Do you have jquery included?

This may be your problem.

If it is included, make sure it's on a line before your script.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, you should make it $(document).ready(function(){code goes here})